# What are the correct camera (quaternion) transformations to change the object view

Tags: vector-spaces, rotations, quaternions

I'm currently working with some camera rotations. The issue is, given a camera in an arbitrary rotation (R) and position (T) in a three dimensional space I want to give the viewer the impression that they are able to rotate any item centred at (0,0,0) by an angle alpha.

This is an example of an arbitrary camera:

[image]

While this is the effect I would like to obtain (car facing forward, rotated by alpha=90º):

[image]

However I would like this effect to be obtained by means of moving the camera only, NOT the car:

[image]

In summary, (A) is the arbitrary camera, in (B) the object is rotated and in (C) the same effect is achieved rotating the camera only.

[image]

The camera position is a three dimensional vector containing the XYZ values while the rotation is represented with a Quaternion. What series of transformations should I apply to the camera to achieve this result ?

Thanks in advance

Comment: Move the camera by applying the desired rotation (the inverse of the desired car rotation) to its position vector, and reorient the camera by pre-composing (multiplying on the right) the rotation with its rotation quaternion (or just re-pointing it at the origin).

Comment: Those series of transforms resolved the issue